# How can I copy/clone a single row from a ResultSet in Java? Multithread implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, resultset

I retrieve a ResultSet with a lot of rows. Each row has to be analyzed, so I'd like to analyze each row in a new thread (don't worry: I won't start all the threads simultaneously, let say 10 in a row). The entire ResultSet will be used exclusively to read data from it (so, it's a kind of a static read-only table).

So what I'd like to do is:

```
ResultSet rs;

public void loadResultSet(){

    ...
    rs = _preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    int rowSize = 0;

    while (rs.next()) {
       rowSize++;
    }


    //this method starts 10 threads simultaneously
    runThreads(rowSize);

     ...

}
```

And...

```
@Override
public void run() {


    //Unknown object that allows me to store a copy of a single row from ResultSet
    Foo foo = rs.absolute(index);

    //Then i can retrieve data just like a normal ResultSet
    String s = foo.getString(1);

    ....
    ....

}
```

Any suggestion?

Samples are really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You are running a thread per row, so why run on the resultSet just to get a count? just start a thread for each row... if you want to cap your threads, used Executors service and use a thread pool of max N (e.g. 10 threads) then feed the threads the task to do on each row.

Comment: That's not the point. Anyway I cannot read from multiple threads into the same ResultSet at different position, and the problem will be the same

Comment: The only reason I would use threads is if the processing of each row takes a lot of time, e.g. you could get the next row but you are blocking on processing the previous, there is no other real benefit of making this multithreaded. Can you please explain what I'm missing?

Comment: I have a lot of rows. For each row I have to test if it's in a list, add one part of its data in a list and another part in another list, check things in the date field (one column per row is a date)..and many more. Because this is a "simple istruction multiple data" context, I've tought that multithreading would be appreciated!

Comment: I would benchmark and see how much time is spent per row processing, but in any case, you should not have one thread per row. you should open a thread pool of a configurable length of workers, each gets a COPY of the resultset values, and does with it whatever needs to be done, this way you are not blocking on a row, though I would do some benchmarks and see if this indeed gives you a visible performance gain. Usually your database is the bottleneck, not the processing... what you COULD do is raise he default fetch size from the database and lower the amount of TCP calls to it...

Answer (score 0):

If I were u, I would rather to execute the queries in separate threads also like:

select * from table_name where mod(id,threadCount)=threadId

Just give an id to each thread and execute them. With this, each thread will have different datas to process

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL and, unfortunately, a thing like that seems pretty slow.

Comment: nop, it depends on your table of course. we have a table and each day 6 million items are being inserted into it. We actually use it with the constraint "insert date", but it is pretty fast for us